# Rich Text Editor removes HTML formatting

Tags: sitecore-client, security, richtext-editor

I have a role that is a member of `Sitecore/Designer`, `Sitecore/Author`, and `Sitecore Client Publishing`.

When I unlock a page it creates a new version and all the Html formatting is deleted on the **Rich Text Editor**. When I log in as `admin` this issue does not happen.

I did provide `read/write` access to the Rich Text Editor for this user. Also played around with the permissions but could not find the problem.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try updating permissions to 'Sitecore Client Authoring' & Sitecore Client Designing'  and check?

Comment: With Sitecore Admin, normally a new version is not created automatically. I do not think the problem is related to your user role, but with the automatic creation of a new version. I think that may cause the html stripping. What Sitecore version re you using?